# Pass by reference or return array in PHP?

Tags: php, pass-by-reference

All of my functions that have multiple parameters and that need to return more than one of those values I return an `array` like so...

```
function eg($a, $b) {
    $a += 5;
    $b += 10;
    return array('a' => $a, 'b' => $b);
}
$no = eg(0, 5);
echo $no['a']; // 5
echo $no['b']; // 10
```

Is this considered bad practice compared to passing by reference ie;

```
function eg(&$a, &$b) {
    $a += 5;
    $b += 10;
}  
eg(0, 5);
echo $a; // 5
echo $b; // 10
```

Does this really matter? When would I want to use one over the other when using the examples above? Is there any difference in performance?

Thanks

Comment: As this is opinion this question probably isn't perfectly suited for this forum, but personally I would say your example above is probably cleaner and done better than passing by reference, which is a bit lazy and if your code is encapsulated well, it makes it hard to see when reading it why your $a and $b values are suddenly different.  I think your first example, personally, is the way to go .

Comment: Sorry about the question I was told to ask it by another member from another one of questions. Thanks for your comment. I am just wondering whether to change my code or not based on whether it is either good or bad practice to do so. But I understand it is easier to understand the first example.

Comment: No yes or no answer indeed, I agree the first example is clearer, and your coworker will thank you for that clarity.

Comment: Thanks @Wrikken. I understand the question is vague but I didn't know where else to ask it!

Comment: Depending on what your real code is supposed to do, it can also make sense to take in parameters and return an object. Or, even better, implement `eg()` as a class method. In the example given, this is overkill... but in a real-world application this approach can be much cleaner.

Comment: I would like to answer the question, but it's closed. Passing an array reference is faster because it avoids having to make a copy of the array. However, it's usually an unnecessary optimisation so you are better off going with what's cleaner, unless the array is large or the function is called many times in a loop. Forgetting a variable is passed by reference can easily be a source of bugs. You can minimise that risk by choosing a good naming convention and being consistent. Eg `set` vs `get` `setDimensions(&$dimensions)`, `getDimensions($dimensions)`.

Answer (score 8):

As most of the comments have pointed out, the first method (returning an array) is cleaner and easier to understand, so by that metric, it's "better".

Depending on your use-case, though, it may even be better not to try and return multiple values at all.  Consider:

```
public function getDimensions() {
    return array(
        'width' => $this->_width,
        'height' => $this->_height
    );
}

$dim = $canvas->getDimensions();
echo $dim['width'], ' x ', $dim['height'];
```

Compared to:

```
public function getWidth() {
    return $this->_width;
}

public function getHeight() {
    return $this->_height;
}

echo $canvas->getWidth(), ' x ', $canvas->getHeight();
```

This is a contrived example, obviously, but imagine that your methods do something expensive instead of frivolous.  Now imagine that you only need the first of the set of values, but since your method calculates *all of them* for every invocation, you have to wastefully calculate everything and discard what you didn't need.